# Why is std::swap not a class template?

Tags: c++

If I have a class template, and I want to add its own `swap()` in `std` namespace:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Widget {
    void swap(Widget &) {}
};

namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    void swap<Widget<T> >(Widget<T> &a, Widget<T> &b)
    { a.swap(b); }
};
```

It is unable to compile, because `std::swap()` is a function template, and a function template can not be partial specialized.

So, why is `std::swap()` not a class template?

Comment: Maybe because the syntax would be awkward. But it should be possible to workaround this using something like `template<typename T, typename=std::enable_if_t<is_widget_v<T>>` (with the obvious implementationof `is_widget_v`), which will participate in overload resolution for all `Widget<>`s. Or, concepts in C++20 will also work.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik，you are right. I try to define a class template, it cannot use like function,and it is very awkward. Class-template-functor is a bad ideal.

Comment: See https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/07/11/the-std-swap-two-step/ and understand that customization points are something that hasn’t had a great solution. Look up swap and argument-dependent lookup (ADL).

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to specialise `swap()` is to use [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

```
Widget<T> a = get_widget(), b = get_widget();
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

This usage will allow you to overload `swap()` in the same namespace as your class type, outside of the `std` namespace:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Widget {
    ...
};

template<typename T>
void swap(Widget<T> &a, Widget<T> &b) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It concerns me that in the book "Effective C++" , in clause 25, it does not recommended overload function in std namespace, we can only specialise the templates.

Comment: In more generic words: functions can not be partially specialized because overloading is much better mechanism for the same use case.